# Reload data in Kendo Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I am using Kendo grid with .net mvc and angular. On some event i need to refresh datasource in grid (another url call) but with different parameter.
I know you can do this by setting dataSource.transport.options.read.url but is there any better way to do it? Like setting parameters on grid which datasource will read on each refresh?

This is my transport config

```
transport: {  read: {
                url: scope.model.readUrl,
                type: scope.model.readAction || 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',

                    },
```

and this is defining of the model (in a controller)

```
$scope.kendoGrid = {
            showActions: true,
            readUrl: /getPayPeriodReportForAllEmployees + "?dateTime=" + $scope.dateTime,

            readAction: 'GET',
            dataObjectName: 'Data',
            totalObjectName: 'Total',
            pageSize: 30,

            fields: {
                ...
            },

            columns: [...]
}
```

So this $scope.dateTime is changeable, and if possible to tell that to the directive so i don't have to send it different url each time a chnage happens.

SO my problem is similar like this one http://www.telerik.com/forums/pass-a-parameter-to-a-datasource#aBBqFUSbE0-K3ecm1Q2fxg

Comment: How is your grid defined, javascript?

Comment: yes, i am using angular. let me know if you need some code, but i think i can manage if someone points me in the right direction.

Comment: I have no experience with angular but code is always good, please post some